# The most effective implementation of conditional join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In T-SQL I have a view, that includes a join:

```
inner join db..address addr
on addr.town = f.town
```

I need to somehow modify this join, if f.town is a specific value (let's say "abc"), it also includes another value (ie. "abcd"). In all other cases it only takes the value of f.town. Like this:

```
inner join db..address addr
on addr.town in ("abc", "abcd")
```

I tried to do this but it doesn't work:

```
inner join db..address addr
on (case when f.town = "abc"
         then addr.town = f.town
         else addr.town in (f.town, "abcd"))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How you wrote the question confuses me. You write `it also includes another value` which makes me think of something like a `UNION` i.e. extra values, from what I have read in the comments and answers you want to `replace` some custom value with another, like joining a towns name with another translation of that or something along that lines? could you clear that up please?

Comment: I was looking for something like the twrowsell's answer. :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this do the trick?

```
inner join db.address addr 
on  f.town = addr.town OR (f.town='abc' AND addr.town ="abcd")
```

Comment: Something like that, but in this case the join will contain towns "abc" and "abcd" even if f.town isn't "abc".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you're trying to create a structure similar to this?
Haven't tested it and it's a messy thing - please provide sample data if you can;

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B   ON 1 =  (   
                            CASE 
                                WHEN A.Moo = B.Moo THEN 1
                                WHEN A.Moo = B.Moo + 'x' THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                            END 
                        )
```

Comment: This sort of thing should be a last resort IMO.